# Mongodb get point on LineString near to a coordinate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can i get a coordinate in a LineString near to another coord? Im getting the whole document and it is not what i need.

This is the model.

```
let travelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    drive: {
        type : { type : String, default : 'LineString' },
        coordinates: []
    }
});
travelSchema.index({drive: '2dsphere'});
```

This is an example of an insert.

```
let travel = new Travel({
    drive: {
        type: "LineString",
        coordinates: [ 
            [ 41.85073, -87.65126 ],
            [ 41.85229, -87.65132 ],
            [ 41.85258, -87.65141 ],
            [ 41.85416, -87.65143 ],
            [ 41.85628, -87.65155 ],
            [ 41.85733, -87.65155 ],
            [ 41.85737, -87.64993 ],
            [ 41.85805, -87.64994 ],
            [ 41.85808, -87.6488 ],
            [ 41.8599, -87.64877 ]
        ]
    }
})
```

This is the query that returns the whole document.

```
const travel = await Travel.findOne({
    drive: {
        $near: {
            $geometry : { 
                type : "Point" , 
                coordinates : myLocation 
            }, 
            $maxDistance : 500
        }
    }
})
```

As the title of the post says i need to get the point that made the document get found. So insted of returning the whole array of points i need to get the nearest one.